# Ipad splitView, is it possible to resize the splitView's rootController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Right now I have a splitview that loads PDFS to a webview.  When the application is in portrait mode, the formatting is correct and it does what it needs to do.  However, when I switch it to landscape mode, the pdf is too large and goes off of the right side of the screen.  How would I fix this?  One solution I can think of is to resize the rootView table, by making it thinner it would open up more space for the PDF.  Any ideas on how to do that? or if it is even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with the default SplitViewController, luckily Matt has written a pretty good one that can do stuff like that!

You can find it at GitHub: https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/